# Cruise Control .NET two project same working directory

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

in ccnet wiki in the project block, workingDirectory I read: "Make sure this folder is unique per project to prevent problems with the build." I want to do two project that has the same working directory... what are the "problems with the build" that can occur and how can I overcome these problems?

Edit:
My situation: I have two applications in the same trunk that has some common code but if I made commit to one of the applications I don't want the other application to build and increase its version number but if I made a change to the common code I want both of them to trigger a build. My source control is SVN and I use [Filtered block](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Filtered) to include only the files I want to trigger a build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

Have a single project that builds just the common code. This should emit its built assembly to a *known location* **outside it's working directory**.

Have 2 other projects that build the other parts of the solution. Each only listens to changes to its particular source control paths. Each project can incorporate/reference the built assembly from the *known location*

The 2 other projects can be forced from the common project using a `forceBuildPublisher`.

These projects should be in the *same queue* to prevent the common project rewriting the built common assembly whist its trying to be reference by the other 2 projects.

**Option 2**

Have 2 individual projects that both build the common source code and the specific code together. Say by building a solution file which contains both sets of projects.

This is the simpler option, but does lose you the neatness of having a 'common assembly version number'

**Pros and Cons**

*Option 1*

1. You have a single version no for each version of the common code.
2. Its more prone to issues due to the additional complexity.
3. You need to maintain a *known location* outside of the working directory so that it is not deleted/cleaned by the build process.

*Option 2*

1. Simpler solution.
2. Common code version is lost in the version of the dependant assembly.

If I had to suggest one, I would opt for for option 2, purely because its simplicity reduces chance of other issues.

Answer (score 0):

Working directory is a place where Cruise Control puts the source code of your project to, and this is also where the build process is happening. If you point two projects to the same working directory, you can end up with any kind of conflicts you can guess. Source files of project A and project B can mix up, the build process might break because of unknown state of the build folder, etc.

It's quite natural to separate unrelated things, and in this case it's a call of common sense. Besides, I can hardly imagine a situation when you have to put 2 projects into the same working directory.

Comment: My situation: I have two applications in the same trunk that has some common code but if I made commit to one of the applications I don't want the other application to build and increase its version number but if I made a change to the common code I want both of them to trigger a build...